# Composer methods of requiring versions

Tags: php, composer-php

I've seen a lot of different ways to require in a dependency.

What is the different between the two following methods?

```
{
    "require": {
        "stripe/stripe-php": "2.*",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#package-names

Answer (score 0):

2.* means anything matching version 2.0 to 2.9

~2.0 means pretty much the same thing in this example. You could view the ~ as starting from the last number, moving up, so ~2.3 would be anything from 2.3 to 2.9.